# Как сохранить позицию CollectionView Cells при выходе из приложения?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь начать работать с Core Data, задача состоит в том, чтобы хранить положение ячеек после выхода из приложения. Подскажите, в какую сторону вообще копать?

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPathForDataItem dataItem: AnyObject) -> IndexPath? {

        if let candidate: Indicator = dataItem as? Indicator {

            for item: Indicator in data[collectionView.tag] {

                if candidate == item {

                    let indicators = data[collectionView.tag]
                    let position = indicators.index { $0 == item }

                    if let position = position {

                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: position, section: 0)
                        return indexPath
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Я правильно понимаю, что именно этот метод отвечает за порядок ячеек? Как вызвать тот же порядок при отрисовке главного VC?

Класс Indicator в данном случае - это NSManagedObject, правильно ли я сохранил порядок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было не таким уж и сложным. В итоге код выглядит частично вот так:

В методе `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

```
if collectionView.tag == 0 {
        indicator.position = "0"
    } else {
        indicator.position = String(indexPath.item + 1)
    }
```

У "индикаторов" есть атрибут Position, который записывается в Core Data.

Далее во ViewDidLoad мы вызываем следующий код:

```
    self.dataManager.getIndicators(with: predicate, success: { (indicators) in

                    let temp = Array(indicators[0..<indicators.count])
                    let indicatorsSorted = temp.sorted( by: { (ind1, ind2) -> Bool in
                        if let pos1 = ind1.position {
                            if let pos2 = ind2.position {
                                return Int(pos1)! < Int(pos2)!
                            }
                        }
                        return false
                    })
                    self.data = [[indicatorsSorted.first!], Array(indicatorsSorted[1..<indicators.count])]
```

Как работаем метод getIndicators, не суть важно.

В итоге мы раздаем позицию ячейке при отрисовке, записываем ее в Core Data, далее при каждом ViewDidLoad вызываем сортировку массива индикаторов по позициям. Задача решена.